# Cypress Psoc 5LP USBUART problem

Tags: usb, uart, psoc

Forgive me in advanced if I don't make this question clear enough, I'm just getting my head around this new device and related terminology.

[image: cypress psoc 5lp]

I just got a psoc 5lp with onboard kitprog - (CY8C5888LTI - LP097) and i am trying to do a basic 'hello world' using USBUART (CDC Interface V3.2) to 'print' the state of the onboard button and I am unable to see any of my putstring commands in my teraterm serial reader.

I have been able to create a working program using the RX connection to my output pin with a 'normal' UART, which is my understanding that uses the kitprog as a serial connection. But am unable to get anything from the USB connection that is directly connected to the psoc I am programming. (socket labelled J5 on board, as shown in picture)

Checking my device manager I can see the KitProg showing under Ports, which is how I understand the 'normal UART' connection was working, but that is it.

I feel like I am missing something really simple, but if anyone can give me a step in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

I am following a tutorial on youtube step by step to no avail.

workspace/code can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/bauerslab/PSoC-Tutorials/tree/master/01%20-%20HelloWorldSerial)

youtube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vezklzw6PxM)

Comment: I am sorry if this seems like a broad question, I guess I am looking for someone who might have experienced a similar problem.

Comment: Is baud rate correct or default?

Comment: I couldn't find out how to set it in psoc creator so I tried them all?!

I could set it with the 'normal' UART, but could not see it with usbuart in psoc creator.

Comment: It is likely 9600 8 1 NP

Comment: alas no joy,   I am going to try a different computer, just as I am running out of things to try.

Comment: Get a DMM an verify Vdc and try earth ground to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a faulty/incompatible USB cable... I am loving life right now.